# Selecting siblings between two nodes using XPath

Tags: html, xpath

How would I select all the tables between the table whose id is header_completed and the first table after the header_completed one that has an align of center? Here is the html I am selecting it from:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center" class="header_completed"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table> <--          -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table> <--          -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table> <-- these 5  -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table> <--          -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table> <--          -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
```

I tried using `//table[@id="header_completed"]/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::table[@align="center"][1]]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a complete solution.

Comment: Damn, you've really done your best to ask a good tricky question. For the full point on usefulness & robust design, I'd very much like to expand it to 2 instances of a `[@class='header_completed']`...some nodes...`[@align='center']`, and capturing those 2 sets in 1 go.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe this XPath expression selects the nodes you want:

```
//table[@class="header_completed"]/
    following-sibling::table[@align="center"][1]/
        preceding-sibling::table[
            preceding-sibling::table[@class="header_completed"]
        ]
```

First I navigate to the `table` with `@class="header_completed"`.

From there I select the first following sibling table with `@align="center"`.

From there I select all preceding sibling tables that have a preceding sibling which is the table with `@class="header_completed"`.

Comment: +1 for an actual workable solution without hardcoded positions, good thinking. However, expanding on it, I was wondering whether you would have any insight in the possibility I posed in the comments to the question: what if we have 2 sequences between nodes that are valid, i.e.: if we copy the example after itself, how to still get the 10 resulting nodes (between `match1_of_start` & `match1_of_end` + `match2_of_start` & `match2_of_end`) instead of the the whole list (between `match1_of_start` & `match2_of_end`).

Comment: +1 A great solution and one that is easy to comprehend. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Wrikken That is a challenge for sure. I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks :)

Answer (score 35):

**Use the Kayessian method of node-set intersection**:

**The intersection of two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2` is** evaluated by the following XPath expression:

```
$ns1[count(.| $ns2)=count($ns2)]
```

**If we have the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center" class="header_completed"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920"></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center"></table>
</t>
```

**then according to the question, we have**:

`$ns1` is:

```
/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                     /following-sibling::*
```

`$ns2` is:

```
/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
             /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                   /preceding-sibling::*
```

We simply substitute `$ns1` and `$ns2` in the Kayessian formula and get the following XPath expression, which selects exactly the wanted 5 elements:

```
/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                         /following-sibling::*
              [count(.|/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                            /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                               /preceding-sibling::*)
              =
               count(/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                            /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                                /preceding-sibling::*)
              ]
```

**To verify that this is really the solution, we use this XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="ns1" select=
      "/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                         /following-sibling::*
      "/>
    <xsl:variable name="ns2" select=
       "/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                 /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                       /preceding-sibling::*
       "/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select=
       "$ns1[count(.| $ns2)=count($ns2)]
       "/>
        <DELIMITER/>
        <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                         /following-sibling::*
              [count(.|/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                            /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                               /preceding-sibling::*)
              =
               count(/*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                            /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
                                /preceding-sibling::*)
              ]
       "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document above, the wanted correct result is produced**:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="920"/>
<DELIMITER/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="920"/>
```

**XPath 2.0 solution**:

In XPath 2.0 we can use the `intersect` operator and the `>>` and/or the `<<` operators.

The XPath 2.0 expression that corresponds to the previously used XPath 1.0 expression is:

```
     /*/*[ .
        >>
         /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
         ]

  intersect

    /*/*[ /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                 /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
             >>
              .
        ]
```

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution, proving the correctness of this XSLT 2.0 expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="ns1" select=
  "/*/*[ .
        >>
         /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
       ]
  "/>

    <xsl:variable name="ns2" select=
       "/*/*[ /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                 /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
             >>
              .
             ]
       "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:sequence select="$ns1 intersect $ns2"/>
  <DELIMITER/>
   <xsl:sequence select=
   "/*/*[ .
        >>
         /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
       ]

  intersect

    /*/*[ /*/*[@class='header_completed'][1]
                 /following-sibling::*[@align='center'][1]
             >>
              .
        ]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied on the XML document defined before, we again get the same wanted, correct result:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="920"/>
<DELIMITER/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="920"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="920"/>
```

Comment: +1 A very insightful answer and one that is very useful. It had great explanations and proofs. Thank you.

Comment: +1 This is the actual answer to the question, and a instructive example of Kayessian formula application as well.