# Can't find the correct XPath expression (to combine results)

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to get a list of proverbs from [wikipedia](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_Nederlandse_spreekwoorden_A-E).

I'm able to select:

- the categories (e.g. "aanval", "aap")
- the proverbs (e.g. "De aanhouder wint.")
- the explanations (e.g. "Wie blijft proberen zijn doel te bereiken, heeft uiteindelijk succes. je moet volhouden.")

but have much difficulty in joining them the correct way. I would like to end up with an array like:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'category' => 'aanval',
    'proverb' => 'De aanval is de beste verdediging.',
    'explanation' => array(
      0 => 'Je kunt in een strijd of ruzie beter zelf actie ondernemen dan afwachten.',
    )
  ),
  1 => array(
    'category' => 'aap',
    'proverb' => 'Al draagt een aap een gouden ring, het is en blijft een lelijk ding.',
    'explanation' => array(
      0 => 'Wie zich mooi aankleedt wordt daarmee zelf nog niet mooi.',
      1 => 'Of: Wie zich kleedt als iemand van aanzien wordt daarmee nog niet aanzienlijk.',
      2 => 'Of: Fraaie kleding en sieraden maken een lelijk mens niet mooi.'
    )
  ),
  2 => array(
    'category' => 'aap',
    'proverb' => 'Als apen hoger klimmen willen, ziet men gauw hun blote billen.',
    'explanation' => array(
      0 => 'Iemand die meer wil dan hij kan, maakt zich snel belachelijk.',
    )
  ),
);
```

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
if ($x = urlToXpath($url, true))
{
  $keywords = array();
  foreach ($x->query('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2/span[@class="mw-headline"]') as $node)
  {
    $keywords[] = trim($node->nodeValue);
  }

  $data = array();
  foreach ($x->query('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/dl/dd/dl') as $node)
  {
    $proverbs = array();
    foreach ($x->query('dd[@style="font-weight: bold"] | dd/b', $node) as $childNode)
    {
      $proverbs[] = trim($childNode->nodeValue);
    }
    $descriptions = array();
    foreach ($x->query('dd[position()>1]/small', $node) as $childNode)
    {
      $descriptions[] = trim(preg_replace('/^((Ook|Of):)/i', '', $childNode->nodeValue));
    }
    $data[] = array('proverbs' => $proverbs, 'descriptions' => $descriptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XPath expression that selects all three wanted nodes per proverb. I also define an algorithm how to populate your arrays using this kind of XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with xpath, you would probably need to select each H2, then use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428104/selecting-siblings-between-two-nodes-using-xpath) to select all the proverb-containing nodes in between. Then do the same thing on those nodes to find the descriptions.

You might find it easier to download the wikitext for the page (e.g. [like this](http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lijst_van_Nederlandse_spreekwoorden_A-E&action=raw)) and process that with a simple text parser over the lines in the text. Or if not that, you should at least use `action=render` to get a version [without all the skin-related HTML](http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lijst_van_Nederlandse_spreekwoorden_A-E&action=render).

Answer (score 0):

**This XPath expression selects the wanted (three) nodes for the  first proverb:**

```
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[1]/span[@class="mw-headline"]
|
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[1]/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd/dl/dd[1]/b 
|  
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[1]/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd/dl/dd[2]/small
```

**The wanted three nodes for the second proverb are selected by this XPath expression** (note that just the index is incremented from `1` to `2`):

```
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[2]/span[@class="mw-headline"]
|
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[2]/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd/dl/dd[1]/b 
|  
 /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/h2[2]/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd/dl/dd[2]/small
```

...etc.

This gives you a good algorithm for filling your arrays -- iterate the index : 1, 2, 3, ...  until for some index K the evaluation of the constructed XPath expression doesn't select any nodes -- then you are finished.