# XPath expression to get all preceding siblings UNTIL condition met

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is my XML:

```
...
<table></table>
<p class="source"></p>
<p class="notes"></p>
<p class="notes"></p>
<p class="notes"></p>
<p />
<p />
...
<table></table>
<p class="notes"></p>
<p class="notes"></p>
<p />
...
```

I am trying to write a template which is called for each `"<p>"` tag.  This template will return the index of where this tag lives relative to it's first preceding `"<table>"` tag.  It should only count `"<p>"` tags that have the attribute "class" equal to "notes".

So for the above example, I'd want the indexes noted in the comments below:

```
...
<table></table>
<p class="source"></p>
// should return 0 <p class="notes"></p>
// should return 1 <p class="notes"></p>
// should return 2 <p class="notes"></p>
<p />
<p />
...
<table></table>
// should return 0 <p class="notes"></p>
// should return 1 <p class="notes"></p>
<p />
...
```

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
 <xsl:template name="PrintTableNumberedNote">
 <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="count(preceding-sibling::p[(@class='notes')])"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$currentPosition"/>.     
 </xsl:template>
```

I need to add logic to make the count stop at the first occurence of the preceding table, because this is how the results incorrectly look with this template:

```
...
<table></table>
<p class="source"></p>
// returns 0 <p class="notes"></p>
// returns 1 <p class="notes"></p>
// returns 2 <p class="notes"></p>
<p />
<p />
...
<table></table>
// returns 3 <p class="notes"></p>
// returns 4 <p class="notes"></p>
<p />
...
```

How do I combine this other criteria to my XPath statement?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to subtract the `p` elements before the preceding `table`:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="
    count(preceding-sibling::p[@class='notes']) -
    count(preceding-sibling::table/preceding-sibling::p[@class='notes']"/>
```

If you want the nodeset containing all the `p` elements between the preceding `table` and the current node, you could try:

```
<xsl:variable name="numTables" select="count(preceding-sibling::table)"/>
<xsl:variable name="paragraphs" select="
    preceding-sibling::p[
        @class='notes' and
        count(preceding-sibling::table) = $numTables]"/>
```

Or, using the variable `$currentPosition` from above:

```
<xsl:variable name="paragraphs" select="preceding-sibling::p
    [@class='notes']
    [position() &lt;= $currentPosition]"/>
```

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428104/selecting-siblings-between-two-nodes-using-xpath).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked like a charm!  I need to find a good path XSLT book - do you recommend any?