# Matching nodes between current node and next with a certain tag-name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have XML structured in the following way:

```
<content>
    <sh1>A</sh1>
    <sh2>A1</sh2>
    <sh2>A2</sh2>
    <sh1>B</sh1>
    <sh2>B1</sh2>
    <sh2>B2</sh2>
    <sh2>B3</sh2>
    <sh1>C</sh1>
    <sh2>C1</sh2>
    <sh2>C2</sh2>
    <sh1>D</sh1>
    <sh2>D1</sh2>
    <sh2>D2</sh2>
    <sh2>D3</sh2>
    <sh2>D4</sh2>
</content>
```

As you can see there are two tag names of concern here: `sh1` and `sh2`.  These represent headers and sub-headers, and I need to organize them as such in the output XML by nesting their contents (you can see example output [here](http://cssdesk.com/xgUxw)).  My approach so far has been to match each `sh1`, and then try to match each `sh2` between it and the next `sh1`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428104/selecting-siblings-between-two-nodes-using-xpath) super helpful question which has gotten me (I hope) most of the way there.  I've thrown together the following XSLT (1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//sh1" />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sh1">
    <li>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="." /></h1>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::sh1[1]/preceding-sibling::sh2[preceding-sibling::.]" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sh2">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem (predictably) is that I can't have the XPath `./following-sibling::sh1[1]/preceding-sibling::sh2[preceding-sibling::.]` using `.` signify that the `sh2` should have the current node as a preceding sibling.  Is there some other keyword I could use?  Or perhaps another approach entirely to get the nested structure I'm going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 I would approach the problem using `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="sh1">
            <li>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="." /></h1>
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ." />
                    </ul>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sh2">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're restricted to 1.0 then a key based approach [as suggested by michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23476627/592139) is probably the most efficient, but the simplest fix to your existing approach would be something like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::sh2[
     generate-id(preceding-sibling::sh1[1]) = generate-id(current())]" />
```

`preceding-sibling::sh1[1]` is the nearest preceding `sh1` to the node we're filtering at the time, and `current()` is the `sh1` element that the template is operating on.  Comparing their `generate-id` values is the XSLT 1.0 way to determine whether the two expressions select *the same node* (if you just compared the values rather than their generated IDs then you risk false positives as two different `sh1` elements with the same text would be considered equal).  In 2.0 you could just use the `is` operator to do this (`preceding-sibling::sh1[1] is current()`).

Alternatively, you can simulate a "while loop" using a technique I've heard referred to as "sibling recursion": apply templates to just the first `sh2` under this heading, and have that template recurse to the next sibling, and so on until we run out of appropriate nodes:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::sh2]" />
</ul>
```

and the template:

```
<xsl:template match="sh2">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::sh2]" />
</xsl:template>
```

The "loop" will terminate as soon as `following-sibling::*[1]` is not an `sh2` element.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of `key`.  I'm trying it out now.  Side question:  Does XSLT have a stack?  and can said [stack overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEi4I6UWuDQ)?  I doubt XSLT can just cull your memory like scheme, or lisp.

Comment: @SandyGifford the XSLT spec simply defines what output a processor must produce for a given set of instructions, it doesn't mandate any particular implementation.  Some processors may apply tail call optimisation to implement a tail-recursive template such as my `sh2` above as a loop rather than a recursion internally - I know Saxon does this, I'm not sure about other processors.

Comment: Thanks for the major knowledge drop.  I've been side tracked, here, but I swear testing this is on my to-do list!

Comment: @SandyGifford "*Thanks for the great explanation of `key`.*" Note that Ian's excellent answer does not explain anything about `key` as such - on the contrary, it describes *alternatives* to using a key. There's no doubt that using a key is the most efficient method to apply here (in XSLT 1.0); IMHO it is also much easier on the eye than an awkward expression like `following-sibling::sh2[generate-id(preceding-sibling::sh1[1]) = generate-id(current())]` - but that could be a matter of what you're used to.

Comment: @michael.hor257k ah, I guess in my head `generate-id` was somehow intrinsically tied to `key`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe using a **key** would be the most convenient approach here:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sh2" match="sh2" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::sh1[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/content">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sh1" />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sh1">
    <li>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="." /></h1>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sh2', generate-id())" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sh2">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```