# How to compare XML tag values and merge them when they are the same? (Python)

Tags: python, xml, tags, elementtree, pdfminer

I have an XML file structured like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

The actual file is way longer. I want to compare the size of the words and merge consecutive words with the same size together, keeping the tags, like this:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <pages>
        <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
        <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
        <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
        <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  ncolour="0" size="12.333">API</text>
        <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  ncolour="0" size="12.482">TOLO III</text>
        </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
    </pages>
```

So far, it was possible to compare the attributes, but I don't know how to keep the tag. This is the code so far to do this:

```py
    words = []
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    pages = root.findall('.//page')
    for page in pages:
        previous_key = None
        current_key = None
        texts = page.findall('.//text')
        for txt in texts:
            if previous_key:
                current_key = (txt.attrib.get('font',previous_key[0]),txt.attrib.get('size',previous_key[1]))
            else:
                current_key = (txt.attrib.get('font','empty'),txt.attrib.get('size','empty'))
            if current_key != previous_key:
                words.append([])
            words[-1].append(txt.text)
            previous_key = current_key

    for group in words:
        if group:
            print(''.join(group))
```

What is that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm missing something in your logic: in your desired output `<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  ncolour="0" size="12.482">TOLO III</text>` you grouped 4 `<text>` nodes with the right `size` attribute value, with another `<text>` node without the correct attribute value (actually, without the attribute at all) and then with the next 3  `<text>` nodes with the right `size` attribute value. Should these be in two (or 3) groups?

Comment: Basically, if I understood well your question, they already are in two groups (two sizes), but the node with no attribute is there just because of the whitespace, this is something I would have handled later on... What I need is for the sizes to be consecutive, this is why there is size 1 -size 2  - size1: I need to keep the order of the letters but still group work tags are repeated. Did I explain myself better?

Comment: I guess that where is we (almost philosophically) disagree, is about the treatment of the empty `<text>` node: a node that doesn't have the attribute `size` at all is equivalent to a node that does the attribute but with the wrong attribute value. So just like `C` is separated from the `TOLO` group because nodes with the wrong size attribute separate them, so should the `TOLO` group be separated from the `III` group because a node with the wrong size attribute (i.e., no size attribute at all) separates them. You don't have to agree, of course, but that would seriously complicate the xpath.

Comment: I see, and you're right! What would you suggest?

Comment: You can take one of two basic approaches: first, tinker with the xml before processing the xpath. So you either delete the empty text node (in which case the group becomes `TOLOIII`) or replace the node with `<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text>` (which gives your current output). Second, live with the xml as is, in which case you get two separate groups `TOLO` and `III`. Obviously, I don't know which options works best for you.

Comment: The second one surely works better for me. How do I keep the tag when iterating lines though? That was the thing I couldn’t do...

Comment: Well, now that we resolved the preliminary issue, I can start thinking about the main problem...

Comment: true, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took me a while to figure it out... I'm not sure it's even relevant still, but since it became sort of a matter of principle for me to resolve it, I'll post it here for future reference.

The fundamental demand of the question is that elements be grouped if they meet certain requirements and if the are consecutive.  The concept is that you select the first element that meets the condition and all its following siblings. Then select the last element that meets the condition and all its preceding siblings. The elements between these two are your targets. In order to that, at least in xpath, you need to use the `intersect()` function.

The problem with that, in turn, is that `intersect()` is an xpath 2.0 function, and main python library for xpath (lxml) only supports xpath 1.0. It is [possible to emulate `intersect()` in xpath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428104/selecting-siblings-between-two-nodes-using-xpath/3428250#3428250), but it is so complicated, it will make your head spin, especially in this case.

So we need to use a python library which supports xpath 2.0. There is one - elementpath. I tried doing it using elementpath, but there I ran into another problem. In this case, applying `intersect()` correctly requires the use of the xpath `count()` function. It turned out, however, that there was a bug in the implementation of `count()` in elementpath. [David Brunato, the author](https://github.com/brunato) kindly addressed the issue and it had been fixed in the most current release of elementpath!

So with all that said, we can now try to solve the actual problem:

```
#I used a simplified version of the xml to streamline things
sizes = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page>
        <box>
            <line>
                <text size="12.482">C</text>
                <text size="12.333">A</text>
                <text size="12.333">P</text>
                <text size="12.333">I</text>
                <text size="12.482">T</text>
                <text size="12.482">O</text>
                <text size="12.482">L</text>
                <text size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text size="12.482">I</text>
                <text size="12.482">I</text>
                <text size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </line>
        </box>
    </page>
</pages>
"""

import elementpath
from lxml import etree
content = sizes.encode('utf-8')
root = etree.XML(content)

godels = elementpath.select(root, '//text[not(./@size = preceding::text/@size)]/@size') #find out how many different  'size' attribute values there are

for godel in godels:
    gc_expres = f'count(//text[@size="{godel}"][not(preceding-sibling::text[1][@size="{godel}"])])' # for each size, create an expression to determine the number of starting positions
    g_cnt = elementpath.select(root,gc_expres) #activate the function
    for i in range(g_cnt):
        loc = i+1 # the range() method, being pythonian, counts from 0; xpath counts from 1
        top = f'//text[@size="{godel}"][(not(preceding-sibling::text[1][@size="{godel}"]) or count(preceding-sibling::text)=0)][{loc}]/(., following-sibling::text[@size="{godel}"])' #the expression for starting at the top and going down
        bot = f'(//text[@size="{godel}"][following-sibling::text[1][not(@size="{godel}")]])[{loc}]/(.,preceding-sibling::text[@size="{godel}"])' #the expression for starting at the bottom and going up
        int_expr = f'{top} intersect {bot}' #the intersect expression
        combo = elementpath.select(root, int_expr) #the intersect function in action!
        newt = ''.join([str((i.text)) for i in combo]) #now that we have the group, create a string of their combined text values
        combo[0].text=newt #replace the text of the first group member with new combined string
        for i in range(1,len(combo)): #the range skips over this first group member
            combo[0].getparent().remove(combo[i]) #remove all other members of the gorup
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

Output:

```
<pages>
    <page>
        <box>
            <line>
                <text size="12.482">C</text>
                <text size="12.333">API</text>
                <text size="12.482">TOLO</text>
                <text/>
                <text size="12.482">III</text>
                <text/>
            </line>
        </box>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your input! I've been running it and it's taking a while- is that normal?

Comment: @Anna It depends on the size of the actual xml, but the code is fairly complicated, though I didn't try to time it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not the cleanest thing i have ever written but it does the job):

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
'''
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

new_txt = ""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

def doit(tag, attrib_list, text="", last_size=0):
  if 'size' in attrib_list.keys():
    if attrib_list['size'] != last_size:
      if last_size != 0 :
        s = f"</{tag}>\n<{tag}"
      else:
        s = f"\n<{tag}"
      for k,v in attrib_list.items():
        s += f" {k}=\"{v}\" "
      if tag == "text":
        s += f">{text}"

    else:
      s = text
      pass
  else:
    s = f"\n<{tag}"
    for k,v in attrib_list.items():
      s += f" {k}=\"{v}\" "
    s += f">"
  return s

for lvl0 in root.iter('pages'):
  new_txt += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"
  new_txt += doit(lvl0.tag, lvl0.attrib)
  for lvl1 in lvl0:
    new_txt += doit(lvl1.tag, lvl1.attrib)
    for lvl2 in lvl1:
      new_txt += doit(lvl2.tag, lvl2.attrib)
      for lvl3 in lvl2:
        new_txt += doit(lvl3.tag, lvl3.attrib)
        last_size = 0
        for lvl4 in lvl3:
          if len(lvl4.attrib) == 0:
            new_txt += " "
          else:
            new_txt += doit(lvl4.tag, lvl4.attrib, lvl4.text, last_size)
            last_size = lvl4.get('size')
        new_txt += f"</text>\n</{lvl3.tag}>\n"
      new_txt += f"</{lvl2.tag}>\n"
    new_txt += f"</{lvl1.tag}>\n"
  new_txt += f"</{lvl0.tag}>"

print(new_txt)
```

Comment: hey, thank you but I would need the library because the text is repeating and pre and post are not always the same!

Comment: @Anna what is your library ? can you add the import at the beginning too ?

Comment: It's XML e tree elementtree!

Comment: @Anna i re-did it with the library

Comment: it work here: https://repl.it/@bamamo68/61184227draft i don't know which python version or setup you have.